# Displaying data from JSON in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, json, dom

What do you think of my code?  I know it is a little rough around the edges but as of two days ago I had no idea how to use jQuery or JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var json = {

    "205100": {
        "success": true,
            "data": {
            "type": "game",
                "name": "MasterKin",
                "steam_appid": 9000,
                "required_age": 40,
                "is_free": false,
                "controller_support": "full",
                "dlc": [212894, 212893, 208575, 208570]
        }
    }

};

var game_name = [];
for (var key in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var item = json[key];
        game_name.push({
            ItemName: item.data.name //Changing the .name to .dlc or .type will then display that result

        });
    }
}
console.log(game_name);
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < game_name.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + game_name[i].ItemName + "</td>");

    $('table').append(tr);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome (again) to Code Review! I'm glad that you were able to fix your code. I've modified your question to fit the task performed by your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the possible rest of your code looks like, so my opinion *might* be wrong. What I don't understand is why a lot of people use jQuery for the slightest bits nowadays. The display of the array could be done like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("displayTable"); //give this ID to your table

for (var i = 0; i < game_name.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = game_name[i].ItemName;
}
```

**Update:**

If you insist on using jQuery, cache the selector in a variable and re-use the variable. Overusing selectors can result in poor performance and since you're using the selector inside a loop this can easily occur.

```
var table = $('#displayTable');

for (var i = 0; i < game_name.length; i++) {
    table.append("<tr><td>" + game_name[i].ItemName + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Furthermore, give useful names to variables. Names like `tr` or `game_name` are not meaningful, try `tableRow` and `gameNames` instead. I updated the [**JSFiddle working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuyzx8js/).

Comment: Thanks for providing an example! I really didn't know I could parse JSON by just using javascript as most of the tutorials I have come by use jQuery to parse Json files.I guess I choose to use jQuery because I was also going to utilise jQuery  Ajax capabilities

Comment: Yes, jQuery makes life easier but in some situations it can be overkill. You can also use AJAX without jQuery, altough I would recommend using it there. Here's an example of [AJAX without jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first).

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information.